# How to avoid delay on element <input type="file"> onChange event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I faced a problem. I have an `input` element and function to show "loading" animation. The problem is that once I drop files or click and select them "loading" animation shown with a few seconds delay (multiple files or big size file).

Note: solution made with Angular 2+ that's why `(change)`

Solution 1:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="true" (change)="uploadImgs($event)"/>
```

JS:

```
uploadImgs(event: any) {
console.log('START UPLOAD!')
this.spinnerService.start();
///restOfTheLogic...}
```

Solution 2: use onDrop event to trigger `this.spinnerService.start();` which show animation

HTML:

```
<div (drop)="spinnerService.start();">
            <input type="file" multiple="true (change)="uploadImgs($event)"/>
        </div>
```

Solution 3: trigger both functions with `onChange/onDrop`

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="true (change)="spinnerService.start(); uploadImgs($event)"/>
```

Output:
In all cases after I drop files, I can see `console.log('START UPLOAD!')` output in the console immediately, but then it's delay before animation actually appears.

Animation function simply:

```
start() {
document.getElementById('loading').classList.remove('hidden');
```

}

I tried to search on my own. But stacked why 1st line `console.log` is executed immediately and 2nd line `this.spinnerService.start();` executed with delay? Is it waiting while `files` data will be read or something else before manipulating with DOM elements?

Is there are any ideas how to avoid such delay?

Comment: The DOM only gets updated after your current JavaScript “block” is finished executing. Most likely your `///restOfTheLogic...` takes a little longer, I assume? Then go research how that can be avoided, https://www.google.com/search?q=dom+update+immediately+longer+running+code

Comment: Maybe I don't see the 'bigger picture' of the problem, but won't (input) instead of (change) help?

Comment: Thank for right direction @CBroe it wasn't that clear for me where is the issue, DOM or JS behavior. Problem solved